# Change Entry to specified range numbers with sql and vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

```
UPDATE trinityitemtemp 
SET entry = 100000 + 1
WHERE entry = 
(SELECT entry from trinityitemtemp LIMIT 1);
```

I have about 288 recordes in my table and they have random entry ( ID ) it's Primary Key so it can't be duplicated
What i want is to give them randomly numbers from 100000 to 100288
I'll be also using a VB.NET timer to run the SQL x 298 times or if there is a way to do it only with SQL or better way merged between SQL and VB.NET so about the VB code will be simple timer to keep clicking the button under count

Button :

```
Timer1.Interval = 100
Timer1.Start()
Dim sqlTexts = {
   SQLCODE
    }
Using _
    conn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString),
    command As New MySqlCommand With {
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        .Connection = conn
    }
    conn.Open()
    For Each sql As String In sqlTexts
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = sql.Count
        For i As Integer = 0 To sql.Count - 1
            If True Then
                ProgressBar1.Value = i + 1
            End If
        Next
        Try
            command.CommandText = sql
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
End Using
```

Timer :

```
 Button1_click(sender, e)
```

Comment: "`SELECT entry from trinityitemtemp LIMIT 1`" SQL is unsorted set of data.. Using `LIMIT` to fetch the "first" record is **meaningless** in MySQL because the MySQL server is free to return anny record in the table as "first" without using `LIMIT` in combination with `ORDER BY`

Comment: I'm not that good in MySQL but in other database I would order by a random number and get the rowid for the new number.

Comment: Random does not mean unique so this might be all for naught

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but this didn't really solve my issue. Maybe I'm not understanding them.

Comment: Any suggestions?